# how to handle the access token in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

This is the boot script code I have added

```
module.exports = function enableAuthentication(server) {
  //enable authentication
  server.enableAuth();
};
```

In postman tool i have tried by setting authorization in header as below for users/logout api (note: I created the `user` model by extending `User` model),

```
authorization LqAHkjJV4JQ7oiW6QrYPeDoJszqUXSSUi7NwTHivKV0jyNK3VSyIyFxon72NfPzZ
```

But iam getting the below error,

```
{"error":{"name":"Error","status":500,"message":"could not find accessToken","stack":"Error: could not find accessToken\n at D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback\\common\\models\\user.js:302:12\n at D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:2056:62\n at D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:1984:11\n at D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:396:17\n at async.each (D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:153:20)\n at _asyncMap (D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:390:13)\n at Object.map (D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:361:23)\n at allCb (D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:1912:15)\n at D:\\zauth\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\connectors\\memory.js:472:7\n at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)\n at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)"}}
```

Also i have tried,

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users/logout?access_token=LqAHkjJV4JQ7oiW6QrYPeDoJszqUXSSUi7NwTHivKV0jyNK3VSyIyFxon72NfPzZ
```

It's not woking, same error

i have to know how to pass the accesstoken @kamal0808

Comment: You need to understand the error first. Let's break this down one by one. Go to your database, and see whether the access token exists in AccessToken collection or not?

Answer (score 0):

The default ACL for built-in User model does not allow listing users:

You can see full configuration here:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Managing-users.html#default-access-controls

> The above ACL denies all operations to everyone, then selectively allows:
>
> - Anyone to create a new user (User instance).
> - Anyone to log in, log out, confirm their identity, and reset their own password.
> - A user to perform deleteById, findById, and updateAttributes on their own User record (instance).

You can not directly modify build-in User model, so you will need to extend it.

**How to pass access token after successful login?**
You have two ways to do that:

- As access_token query parameter (Not recommended). Example:
  http://localhost:3000/api/users/me/orders?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN
- As "Authorization: HTTP header (Recommended). Example:
  Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN

You should use HTTP headers, because using query parameters is not secured enough (they are not crypted by SSL protocol and could stay in browser or other client history).

Check for more information the documentation: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html

Comment: ok assuming that i have created a custom model(user) extends built-in (User model),Once after i call login api ill get access token.My question is how to pass that access token in authorization header so that i call all other methods like (GET user).

Comment: i have tried GET user in PostMan tool by setting in header tab like,key as authorization and value as (the access token i got after login),but still iam getting authorization required error

Comment: is that i have to set ACL like $authenticated for user custom model to GET user api ?????

Comment: I have updated my question. If you want to get user details you are able to query only your own user id which you successfully logged in (see default ACL for users: findById operation is allowed only for $owner)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ACLs(Access Control Levels) for every API request for the application.

Here's the doc link for ACLs:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html

For your code, you need to get the following object in ACLs array of your **Users.json** file:

```
{
   "accessType": "EXECUTE"
   "principalType": "ROLE",
   "principalId": "$authenticated",
   "permission": "ALLOW",
   "property": "find"
}
```

**$authenticated** refers to anybody who can log in. You can create custom roles for users too.

Comment: ok assuming that i have created a custom model(user) extends built-in (User model),Once after i call login api ill get access token.My question is how to pass that access token in authorization header so that i call all other methods like (GET user). 
     
i have tried GET user in PostMan tool by setting in header tab like,key as authorization and value as (the access token i got after login),but still iam getting authorization required error
     
is that i have to set ACL like $authenticated for user custom model to GET user api ?????

Comment: You need to enable auth service in loopback. Try to setup a boot script for the same. Read http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html#enabling-authentication. It automatically sends request with Access Token in them.

Comment: @user7369339 did you try setting up the boot script? What's the status of your problem?

Comment: module.exports = function enableAuthentication(server) {
  // enable authentication
  server.enableAuth();
};

Comment: @user7369339  
Try setting `"loopback#token": {}` in `middleware.json` under `"initial:before"`